# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.Sqlconnection'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I am getting this error:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.Sqlconnection'

for this code:

```
SqlConnection con1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;
```

How do I solve this problem? I am working with a Windows application.

Comment: You should really accept answers that solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you to all who answered my question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
using(SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString))
{
   // do something with con1
}
```

Note: this is better than the other answers because it includes another hint: use the using keyword to guarantee disposal of your connection object and therefore prevent connection pool problems.  :)

The reason you were getting the error in the fist place is that you were trying to assign a string value   (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString) to a variable of type SqlConnection.

I suggest you learn more about variable typing, variable casting and type assignments in C#, it will make coding a much more pleasurable (less frustrating) experience.

Good Luck!

Comment: can you put value of ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString here

Comment: @DeveloperX - the value of that will depend on what's in the app.config file.

Comment: not sure why you're adding that comment here developerx - did you maybe mean to add it to the original question?  not clear, sorry...

Comment: @Nathan: Thank you. Your answer helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString` is a String to holds the connection information.

You need to create an instance of SqlConnection and pass in the connection string value.

SqlConnection sqlConnection = new `SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);`

Answer (score 0):

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString)) { 
    con.Open(); 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
    string expression = "Parameter value"; 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
    cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure"; 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", 
                SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;    
    cmd.Connection = con; 
    using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    { 
        if (dr.Read()) 
        { 
        } 
    } 
}
```