# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection: Open and Close SqlConnection with methods, Read and Write in Main method

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, using, sqlconnection

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace dbsql
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public SqlConnection mssql = new SqlConnection();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Variables
            string nameVal = "";
            string dateVal = "";
            string catVal = "";
            double amntVal = 0;
            string sqlRec = "";
            int idVal = 0;
            int cnt = 1;

            // Configure and open SQL connection

            MainClass mc = new MainClass();

            mc.OpenSQLConnection("localhost", "trainning");

            //MainClass.OpenSQLConnection("localhost", "trainning");

            /*
             * Truncate the target table(s)
            */
            using (SqlCommand sqlDelete = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM expenses_stage", mc.mssql))
            {
                sqlDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            try
            {
                /*
                 * Retrieve records from source
                */
                SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;
                SqlCommand selectExp = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM expenses_source ORDER BY ID", mc.mssql);
                sqlReader = selectExp.ExecuteReader();

                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    /*
                     * Read source data into vars, trim for clean strings
                    */
                    idVal = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["ID"]);
                    nameVal = sqlReader["Name"].ToString().Trim();
                    dateVal = sqlReader["Date"].ToString().Trim();
                    catVal = sqlReader["Category"].ToString().Trim();
                    amntVal = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["Amount"]);

                    sqlRec = "==> " + idVal + " | " + nameVal + " | " + dateVal + " | " + catVal + " | " + amntVal;

                    /*
                     * Check for blank, NULL, 0 values
                    */
                    if (idVal == 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write("ID is NULL : ");
                        Console.WriteLine(sqlRec);
                    }
                    else if (nameVal == "")
                    {
                        Console.Write("Name is NULL : ");
                        Console.WriteLine(sqlRec);
                    }
                    else if (dateVal == "")
                    {
                        Console.Write("Date is NULL : ");
                        Console.WriteLine(sqlRec);
                    }
                    else if (catVal == "")
                    {
                        Console.Write("Category is NULL : ");
                        Console.WriteLine(sqlRec);
                    }
                    else if (amntVal == 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Amount is NULL : ");
                        Console.WriteLine(sqlRec);
                    }
                    else
                        /*
                         * If food cost is over $200, reject
                        */
                        if (catVal == "Food" && amntVal > 200)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Food expense is too high : ");
                            Console.WriteLine(sqlRec);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("Good record : ");
                            Console.WriteLine(sqlRec);

                            Console.WriteLine(" ====> AER FIRE--Inserting record!");

                            /*
                             * For every source record, insert two records to the target
                            */
                            for (cnt = 1; cnt <= 2; cnt++)
                            {
                                if (cnt == 1)
                                {
                                    SqlCommand insertExp = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO expenses_stage (ID, Name, Date, Category, Amount) " +
                                        "VALUES (" + idVal + ", '" + nameVal + "', '" + dateVal + "', '" + catVal + "', " + amntVal + ")", mc.mssql);

                                    insertExp.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    SqlCommand insertExp = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO expenses_stage (ID, Name, Date, Category, Amount) " +
                                        "VALUES (" + idVal + ", '" + nameVal + "', '" + dateVal + "', 'AP', " + amntVal + ")", mc.mssql);

                                    insertExp.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            mc.CloseSQLConnection();

            Console.ReadKey();
        } //Close main

        public void OpenSQLConnection(string sqlServer, string sqlDatabase)
        {
            string connString = "server=" + sqlServer + ";" +
            "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
            "database=" + sqlDatabase + "; " +
            "connection timeout=30;" +
            "MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

            using (var mssql = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                // Open SQL connection
                try
                {
                    mssql.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }

        }

        public void CloseSQLConnection()
        {
            MainClass mc = new MainClass();

            try
            {
                /*
                 * Close SQL connection
                */
                mc.mssql.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to teach myself C# and how to use it to interact with a database. This program opens a connection to SQL Server, retrieves records from a source table, validates the data a bit, and then writes two records to the target table per source record. Initially all of this code was linear and in the Main method but I wanted to be able to re-use the Open and Close instructions, and use the Open instructions for other servers/databases.

When I created the `OpenSQLConnection` and `CloseSQLConnection` methods I had a lot of trouble as instances were something I was unfamiliar with. I got errors like

> Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection" and reading various threads pointed me to the using function ([Cannot implicitly...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262143/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-data-sqlclient-sqlconnection), [Error while converting string...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262143/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-data-sqlclient-sqlconnection)).

Once I implemented the using function, the errors and warnings went away, but when I run the code the connection isn't working, and I don't think it's actually opening at all. Here is a sample portion of the output (It's pretty long).

> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   at dbsql.MainClass.OpenSQLConnection(String sqlServer, String sqlDatabase) in c:\Users\tromik\Documents\Projects\dbsql\Program.cs:line 153
>   ClientConnectionId:8eb63155-4ec6-4795-9f68-98b01f650ffc
>   Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11

SQL Stuff:

```
-- Create source table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[expenses_source]
(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Amount] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

-- Create target table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[expenses_stage]
(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Amount] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

-- Insert source data
INSERT [dbo].[expenses_source] ([ID], [Name], [Date], [Category], [Amount]) 
VALUES (1, 'Maryland Duford  ', CAST(0x0000A33D00000000 AS DateTime), 'Gas', 70);

INSERT [dbo].[expenses_source] ([ID], [Name], [Date], [Category], [Amount]) 
VALUES (2, 'Suzanne Sechrist  ', CAST(0x0000A35F00000000 AS DateTime), 'Food', 30);

INSERT [dbo].[expenses_source] ([ID], [Name], [Date], [Category], [Amount]) 
VALUES (3, 'Reggie Nally  ', CAST(0x0000A35200000000 AS DateTime), 'Food', 22);

INSERT [dbo].[expenses_source] ([ID], [Name], [Date], [Category], [Amount]) 
VALUES (6, 'Stefani Rochell  ', CAST(0x0000A2A600000000 AS DateTime), 'Hotel', 110);

INSERT [dbo].[expenses_source] ([ID], [Name], [Date], [Category], [Amount]) 
VALUES (10, 'Chong Hecht', CAST(0x0000A3AE00000000 AS DateTime), 'Office', 100);

INSERT [dbo].[expenses_source] ([ID], [Name], [Date], [Category], [Amount])
VALUES (8, 'Tiffaney Tooker  ', CAST(0x0000A40C00000000 AS DateTime), 'Food', 500);

INSERT [dbo].[expenses_source] ([ID], [Name], [Date], [Category], [Amount]) 
VALUES (4, 'Joseph Takemoto  ', NULL, 'Hotel', 100);

INSERT [dbo].[expenses_source] ([ID], [Name], [Date], [Category], [Amount]) 
VALUES (5, 'Bryon Bettis  ', NULL, 'Food', 17);

INSERT [dbo].[expenses_source] ([ID], [Name], [Date], [Category], [Amount]) 
VALUES (9, 'Elfreda Byun  ', NULL, 'Gas', 50);

INSERT [dbo].[expenses_source] ([ID], [Name], [Date], [Category], [Amount]) 
VALUES (11, 'Rosio Boggs ', CAST(0x0000A2F100000000 AS DateTime), NULL, 20);

INSERT [dbo].[expenses_source] ([ID], [Name], [Date], [Category], [Amount]) 
VALUES (7, 'Gregg Smithey  ', CAST(0x0000A29500000000 AS DateTime), 'Food', 8);
```

If more output would help I'm happy to oblige. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the connection object creation in a using block. The using block will close the connection when you exit its scope because the SqlConnection implements IDisposable.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Patrick. Would you recommend not implementing the using block at all, or to simply move the object creation outside the using block? How would I accomplish this?

Comment: @tromik: the `using() { ... }` block is the preferred way of doing things - but you should do this very "local" to the execution of the query. So each query you execute ideally should **(1)** create the `SqlConnection` (in a `using` block), **(2)** create the `SqlCommand` (again - in a `using` block), **(3)** open connection, execute query, close connection. That's the generally accepted best practice - don't open your connection way before you need it, don't close it much later than you've executed the query

Comment: Would it OK to configure/setup the connection in a separate method (so I can define the source separate from the transformations/loads), and then open, use, and close the connection in the main method?

Comment: @tromik You could look at how EntityFramework does it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx. Essentially they wrap the DbConnection lifecycle in a higher level object. The lifetime of the connection is the lifetime of the DbContext. You then create the higher level object in a using scope and call methods on the higher level object. You could also look at the Repository and Unit of Work patterns.

Comment: @tromik  Addition to my previous comment, found a blogpost that lays out how to do the repository pattern without using Entity Framework. http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/ado-net-the-right-way/

Comment: @PatrickHuber Thanks for the links! I did get it to work, but always looking for improvements.